# python extract value from for-loop into another for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, boto3

I'm using boto3 and with a for-loop that gets all the spot requests and their respective instance IDs. It then checks these instances to see if they are running, stopped, or pending, and if none of these then it must be terminated and so I want it to cancel the linked spot request.

The issue I'm having is I can't figure out how to put the outputted spot instance ID into the next for loop to check if that instance is running. My code so far is:

```
 #!/usr/bin/python3
import boto3
import pprint
ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', 'eu-west-1')
spot_requests = ec2.describe_spot_instance_requests()
describe_instance = ec2.describe_instances()

for index in spot_requests['SpotInstanceRequests']:
    instanceID = index["InstanceId"]
    instanceState = index["State"]
    spotRequestID = index["SpotInstanceRequestId"]
    if instanceState != 'active':

            print(f'This instance {instanceID} is {instanceState}')

            for item in instanceID:
                    if item["instanceID"],item["State"] == "Running" or item["instanceID"],item["State"] == "Stopped" or item["instanceID"],item["State"] == "Pending"
                            print(f'{instanceID} is not terminated so do not cancel spot request {spotRequestID}')

                    else
                            print(f'Instance is terminated. Cancel spot request {spotRequestID}')
    else:
            print(f'{instanceID} is {instanceState} and has a request ID of {spotRequestID}')
```

it works well down to this line

```
print(f'This instance {instanceID} is {instanceState}')
```

but I can't continue from here as it keeps giving me errors that I don't understand. I'm not sure if the commas are right but there seems to be no clear answer I can find for where commas should be. any help would be great, thanks

Comment: it looks like the line you are talking about is indented twice, witch would cause an error

Comment: what's the error ?